# Touchbar Buttons

Tags: macos, mac, touch-bar

Is it possible to make buttons on the touchbar activate when I release my finger instead of when I press down? I want them to behave like UI elements in MacOS or web pages.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make buttons on the touchbar activate when I release
>   my finger instead of when I press down?

The Touchbar is designed to be an extension of the keyboard not a web UI.  The keyboard, naturally, activates when you depress a key and the Touchbar mimics this functionality.

There are ways to change this functionality where something happens once the key is released.  For instance, [ControllerMate](https://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) allows you to send text, keypresses, etc. when the depending on the state of the keypress.  The caveat here is that it's a 3rd party application *intercepting* the key presses and modifying them.  The default behavior of the keyboard remains unchanged.

So, can it be done?

It's possible, but it will have to be done within the application itself.  It's not something that can be modified globally.

Comment: Did anyone actually "design" it that way, or was it just a no-thought result?  Sometimes one has fat fingers and touches in slightly the wrong place.  The ability to slide across to the correct icon and have it activate on release would be a wothwhile  accessibility improvement.